# Blank page with HTML displaying XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I have a html document, which creates a table with data, provided by a xml archive. In the live preview of adobe brackets, i can see the page and the data.

But, when i try to open in some browser, like IE, Firefox or Chrome, the page shows up, just in blank.

Here it's part of the code of the html, and below, code of the xml.

this is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

table { border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Futura, Arial, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #777; }
caption { font-size: larger; margin: 1em auto; }
th, td { padding: .65em; }
th, thead { background: #000; color: #fff; border: 1px solid #000; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #ccc; }
tr:hover { background: #aaa; }
td { border-right: 1px solid #777; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","prueba_new.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table><tr><th>CardN</th><th>CardC</th><th>CardE</th><th>CardNe</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CCard");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CardN")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CardC")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CardE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
      document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CardNe")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the xml code, of course, the actual xml file, contains a several hundreds of entries.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<numbers>
<CCard>
<CardNe>Volkervun</CardNe>
<CardN>10000034999</CardN>
<CardC>Red Team</CardC>
<CardE>Volker.vcd</CardE>
</CCard>
<CCard>
<CardNe>Lady Mars</CardNe>
<CardN>10009899899</CardN>
<CardC>Blue Team</CardC>
<CardE>LadyM.vcd</CardE>
</CCard>
</numbers>
```

I try several things, but none of them works.
Some idea for that blank page?

Comment: `document.write`, do the browsers still support that? A much better approach is to build the whole table in memory (in a string variable) and then put it in a container element using `[the container element].innerHTML = [the string variable];`

Comment: While document.write is ugly and outdated technology, I don't believe it is the culprit. Do you see any script error in the developer console? Can you try put some static text immediately after <body> and immediately before </body> to confirm the page is properly loaded?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to open as file without using a local web server. Security will restrick ajax that way

Comment: @charlietfl even if it's in the same directory on the same server?

Comment: Sorry for all the time. Well, the xml document it's in the same dir than the page. but still not charge the table at all.
Can you explain some more of the .innerHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the file in your browser just by double-clicking the .html file on your computer, then you're opening it under the `file://` protocol. The GET request for the XML file will fail because of browser cross-origin sandboxing: *every* page under `file://` is treated like a separate domain, so your .html page isn't allowed to read your .xml file.

It works in Brackets because Live Preview loads up a simple local webserver, so your page is viewed in the browser under the `http://` protocol instead. To replicate the effect without Brackets, run a different local webserver.

My personal favorite simple webserver for testing is [serf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serf) - if you have NodeJS installed on your computer, you can install it by typing `npm install -g serf` on the command line. Then you can start up the server just by typing `serf` in whatever folder your .html file is in.